# Dynamically bind columns from Dictionary to Silverlight DataGrid

Tags: silverlight

I want to bind a collection of objects to a DataGrid in Silverlight. The objects belong to the following type:

```
public class Seats
{
    Dictionary<Group, long> dctValues = new Dictionary<Group, long>();

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<Group, long> Values
    {
        get { return dctValues; }
    }
}
```

Whereas, Group is represented by:

```
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to generate columns based on the dictionary of groups, where each column would have the header set to *Group.Name* and the cell value for each item equal to the *long* value in the dictionary.

Comment: So far we have a header a column and a cell value in that column.  How many other cells would you expect the column to have?  IOW where do the rows come from?

Comment: Let's say we have List<Seats> that contains 5 items, where each will have 3 groups having their name property respectively "GroupA", "GroupB" and "GroupC".

The 5 items are divided as follow:

Item1: Id: 1, GroupA: 100, GroupB: 200, GroupC: 300 
Item2: Id: 2, GroupA: 1000, GroupB: 2000, GroupC: 3000

Comment: ok next question which may take a little thinking about.  Two different instances of `Seats` (each a member of this `List<Seats>`) both have an entry in their respective `Values` dictionary for a Group that has the name "GroupA".  Do they both reference a single instance of `Group` __or__ do they each have their own different instance of `Group` that both happen to have the same value for `Id` and `Name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume that we can't guarantee that there is only a single instance of a `Group` class for each group name.  (Else you would be generating columns based on a list of known groups no?)

Here is a class derived from `DataGrid`:

```
public class SeatsGrid : DataGrid, IValueConverter
{
    public SeatsGrid()
    {
        AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    }
    #region public List<Seats> SeatsList

    public List<Seats> SeatsList
    {
        get { return GetValue(SeatsListProperty) as List<Seats>; }
        set { SetValue(SeatsListProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SeatsListProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SeatsList",
            typeof(List<Seats>),
            typeof(SeatsGrid),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSeatsListPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnSeatsListPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SeatsGrid source = d as SeatsGrid;
        List<Seats> value = e.NewValue as List<Seats>;
        source.OnSeatsListPropertyChanged(value);
    }

    private void OnSeatsListPropertyChanged(List<Seats> value)
    {
        ItemsSource = null;
        Columns.Clear();

        var groups = value
            .SelectMany(seats => seats.Values.Keys)
            .Select(g => g.Name)
            .Distinct();

        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            DataGridTextColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn();
            col.Binding = new Binding()
            {
                Converter = this,
                ConverterParameter = group
            };
            col.Header = group;
            Columns.Add(col);
        }

        ItemsSource = value;
    }
    #endregion public List<Seats> SeatsList

    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Seats seats = (Seats)value;
        string group = (string)parameter;

        Group actualGroup = seats.Values.Keys.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Name == group);
        if (actualGroup != null)
        {
            return seats.Values[actualGroup].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Place an instance of this class in Xaml and assign a `List<Seats>` to its `SeatsList` property and it generates the columns and renders the rows.

**How does it work?**

The magic starts in the `OnSeatsListPropertyChanged` method.  It first gets a list of distinct Group names. It generates a new Text column for each group name setting the header naturally to the group name.

The weird stuff appears when setting the binding for the column. The binding is given a converter which for convience I decided to implement on the `SeatsGrid` class as well.  The converter parameter is the group name.  Since no path is specified the whole `Seats` object will be passed to the converter when binding actually occurs.

Now looking at the `IValueConverter.Convert` method.  It finds an instance (is any) of `Group` in the seats that has the same name as the converter parameter.  If found uses that `Group` as the key to lookup a value to return.

If the Groups were known to be unique per name then the code can be simplified but the principle is the same.

Comment: Perfect! The converter actually does it. Thanks a lot!